# Number game algorithm

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing some research at the moment into creating a new maths game for primary school children where divs from 0-9 appear at random inside a container.

A question is given at the beginning. Something like, multiples of 20. The user will then have to click on the correct ones, and they will then be counted at the end and a score will be given.

So at the moment I have the basic structure, divs pop up and you click them and it adds to the correct answer, meaning there is no wrong answer at this point in time.

I want to know what the best way of determining the right and wrong answers is. Is there and algorithm that I can use that will work out whether the answers are right or wrong, and how would I link it to the divs?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="char1" class="character right1" vaule="1"></div>
    <div id="char2" class="character right2" vaule="2"></div>
    <div id="char3" class="character right3" vaule="3"></div>
    <div id="char4" class="character right4" vaule="4"></div>
    <div id="char5" class="character right5" vaule="5"></div>
    <div id="char6" class="character right6" vaule="6"></div>
    <div id="char7" class="character right7" vaule="7"></div>
    <div id="char8" class="character right8" vaule="8"></div>
    <div id="char9" class="character right9" vaule="9"></div>
    <div id="char9" class="character right0" vaule="0"></div>
</div>
```

wrong answers will be given the class ".wrong" as apposed to ".right"

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SKB3Q/10/

Comment: Personally, I would split this into two components. One which generates the questions and knows the correct answers. And one which will only act on those values. This way you can concentrate on your requirements separately.

Comment: So you are saying start doing the questions and then branch off for each one? @Yoshi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is come up with a question for any notion of right or wrong to make sense.

For example: "Click all numbers that are greater than 20"

The second thing you need to do is express this question as a boolean expression that evaluates to true or false.

```
(selection>20)
```

Then evaluate this expression for each selection to determine whether it is right or wrong.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cFKHq/show/) is an example of what I mean. Before the game starts, the script adds the appropriate class to each element. The question is "Select all numbers greater than 5"

Comment: I see so you just mean start with a place to determine the wrong answers. Then start sorting them into their places? @Asad

Comment: @Milo-J see the example I have attached

Comment: So how would I do multiples of 10? Like this? function multiples10(value){
            return (value == 1 || 2|| 5);
          
        }

Comment: Your rightwrong function should return a value of true if passed an argument that is a multiple of 10, or false if it is not. It should return `(value % 10) == 0`, which is true for multiples of 10 and false for others. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/cFKHq/1/show/) is an example for multiples of 2.

Comment: So what if I had two or more different ones. How would I then get the program to pick one at random before the game started. @Asad

Comment: You would make two separate functions, eg rightwrong1 and rightwrong2, and based on a number randomly generated at the beginning of correctlabels, use that as your condition.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18399/discussion-between-milo-j-and-asad)

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have done  balloon game which resembles this...

As you have done the design and animation work perfectly 70% of work is done :D, small modifications in the logic will complete the work......

My solution will be :
if the div's in the container are static and you have given the ID's for them then 
Step1: check for which div is Clicked and then what value is assigned to it

Step2: check the boolean expression (according to you requirement) here and increase the correct flag or the incorrect flag, which are declared globally, according to your boolean expression

The sample code that might help you

```
for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
{
    $("#char"+i).click(function(){
        //boolean expression comes here
        //increase the correct count or the incorrect count you want to do it
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Its good to know I am that far along, I thought I had a bit of a journey to go. I don't suppose you have a fiddle that would help me do you? @Raghurocks

Comment: For that you are supposed to give the exact requirements so that someone or the other in this group can help you..... :D

Comment: Yeah could you show me what you mean with a multiples of 15 example @Raghurocks

Comment: I have given you in the above answer by considering the multiples of 15 by considering the char1,...as the random div's refer that answer :D

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see exactly the code of yours if the char1,char2,char3,.... are the randomly created divs and 1,2,3,..... are the values associated with that then try this code and let me know

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        $("#char" + i).click(function () {
            var val = $("#char" + i).val(); // so by this you will get the which one is clicked
            if (val % 15 == 0)
                hit++;
            else
                miss++;

            $("#hit").html("correct: " + hit);
            $("#miss").html("Incorrect: " + miss);
        })
    }
</script>
```

so by this when ever a div is enabled, and the user clicks on it then this function is called and will check the boolean expression and increase the hit or miss flags appropriately .

Note: Assuming that Char1,char2,... are the randomly enabling divs, if not write the condition for the appropriate randomly created div's, that will work fine

"you can check for any multiples just by changing the boolean expression, I had given above that is (val%15 == 0 )"